# Is hard coding "width" in web design acceptable?

Tags: html

This is my first expericne with WebDesign and I am designign a form with textboxes, labels, etc... and have a question: is it Ok to set hard coded width for these contorls? or I should everwhere use other techniques for example DIV and percentages on different DIVS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

External CSS files should be used whenever possible. The only exception I've seen to this is when JavaScript is involved, because it will set inline styles when modifying elements (which, there isn't much you can do about, so it's the exception).

Inline styles are frowned upon because

- It only affects that element, rendering it useless as soon as you have another element that needs that same style.
- It makes your code very hard to maintain, because you have to touch every file to make a change when everything's inline.
- It defeats the purpose of the cascade part of cascading style sheets (inline styles always have higher priority than non-inline styles), and can lead to unexpected results when trying to change external styles and something isn't changing as it should.
- Things like `width=100px` on most elements are deprecated or at least discouraged by the W3C.
- It violates separation of presentation and content.
- It leads to a lot of replication, which violates DRY principles.

Comment: I meant is something like <textbox id = "txtPosition" width = "147px"> is a Bad Design?

Answer (score 2):

It should be avoided for the most part because it makes more work for you later if and when you want to change the layout.  The one exception to this rule is images that aren't being used as part of the user interface, as they all tend to have different sizes anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This question needs clarifying, don't you mean using fixed pixel dimensions rather than percentages, the definitions of those dimensions being either in the style sheet or code?

Put it this way, there is a lot of stuff out there that is hard coded with width and height dimensions cast in stone. Yet strategies are found to make these pages workable on widescreen televisions with eyeballs 6 foot away and on phones with eyeballs size inches away. My advice is to concentrate on the usability of your form and let 'form follow function'.

Comment: yeh I meant is something like <textbox id = "txtPosition" width = "147px">  is a Bad Design?

Comment: Yes that is. You should have a style sheet and give everything ids and classes so as to have maximum flexibility. Then, in your stylesheet put everything in, e.g. '.inputs-top {}', '.inputs-middle {}' and so on - with the empty brackets placeholders. Then in Firebug you can quickly style up your form. By this stage you may have the functionality sussed, therefore able to quickly get it all working. The ideal is to use percentages and then you can scale a form to available screen area.

Comment: @Matthew - Giving everything classes and IDs is known as Classitis, and is something to be avoided. Classes and IDs should be given only when needed.

Comment: @Shauna - I hear you, but, with a form, I like to validate the inputs and maybe drive some logic to update other boxes or provide imperial/metric conversions. Some events are best handled on a class level, e.g. on keypress for number validation whereas updating boxes is a lot easier if you can refer to ids. This helps with even the simplest name and address forms where you want Title Case for names, email addresses to be valid and so forth. Questioner sounded to me like he is making quite a form and could probably do with a framework to use e.g. $F instead of a plain form.

Comment: @Matthew - I'm not saying never use classes or IDs, but your explanation is a far cry from "give *everything* ids and classes." Not using them at all is about as good an idea as having useless ones on everything just for the sake of having IDs and classes on everything.

Comment: @Shauna maybe I am suggesting a bad habit, but forms for me need to be a cut above when it comes to usability. Coding this up is not easy hence I like to have classes and ids on everything so the design can be done on the classes and the logic done on ids (rather than $F because I am not that good a coder!).

Answer (score 1):

It is generally frowned upon these days, but people are quick to pour scorn on any layout which isn't "liquid" or "fluid" with auto-sizing columns etc.

If your layout calls for it (a grid, table, etc.) then fixed widths are perfectly acceptable - just make sure you do as much of the stying as you can in a CSS file, it'll be easier to maintain than doing it inline.

Answer (score 1):

Always user CSS to set any dimensions so you don't have to edit your HTML to update the style.

HTML:

```
<div class="my_class">Stuff</div>

<div id="my_id">More Stuff</div>
```

CSS:

```
.my_class { width:150px; }
#my_id { width:125px; }
```